Responsive object not working in options object
Using

NextJS 14
TailwindCSS 3
Typescript
@tsparticles/engine ^3.3.0
@tsparticles/react ^3.0.0

Problem
The responsive object does not seem to work
In my options, I want to disable interactivity below a screen width of 1024px, I am trying to accomplish this by adding a responsive array in the options but it has no effect.
particles-data.ts
import type { ISourceOptions } from "@tsparticles/engine";

const theme = {
  particleColor: "#E44805",
  linkColor: "#B41817",
  zindex: {
    value: -50,
  },
  background: {
    color: "#0F0909",
  },
};

// Object containing code for the interactivity being enabled
const interactivityEnabled = {
  events: {
    onHover: {
      enable: true,
      mode: "grab",
      parallax: {
        enable: true,
        smooth: 10,
        force: 60,
      },
    },
    onClick: {
      enable: true,
      mode: "push",
    },
    onDiv: {
      enable: true,
      mode: "repulse",
    },
  },
  modes: {
    grab: {
      distance: 400,
      links: {
        opacity: 1,
      },
    },
    bubble: {
      distance: 400,
      size: 40,
      duration: 2,
      opacity: 0.8,
    },
    repulse: {
      distance: 200,
    },
    push: {
      quantity: 4,
    },
    remove: {
      quantity: 2,
    },
  },
};

// Object containing code for the interactivity being enabled
const interactivityDisabled = {
  events: {},
  modes: {},
};

// Actual options being passed to the Particles component
export const particlesConfig: ISourceOptions = {
  key: "parallax",
  name: "Parallax",
  responsive: [
    {
      maxWidth: 1024,
      mode: "canvas",
      options: {
        interactivity: interactivityEnabled,
      },
    },
  ],
  interactivity: interactivityDisabled,
  particles: {
    zIndex: {
      value: -50,
    },
    number: {
      value: 70,
      density: {
        enable: true,
      },
    },
    color: {
      value: theme.particleColor,
    },
    shape: {
      type: "circle",
    },
    opacity: {
      value: {
        min: 0.1,
        max: 0.5,
      },
      animation: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 3,
        sync: false,
      },
    },
    size: {
      value: {
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
      },
      animation: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 20,
        sync: false,
      },
    },
    links: {
      enable: true,
      distance: 150,
      color: theme.linkColor,
      opacity: 0.4,
      width: 1,
    },
    move: {
      enable: true,
      speed: 2,
    },
  },
  background: theme.background,
};

You can see in the responsive object I am defining a maxLength of 1024 pixels. I want the interactivity to be enabled after 1024 pixels and be disabled below 1024 pixels however no such effect is made.
I am loading that object here (being passed as props)
particles-background.tsx
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Particles, { initParticlesEngine } from "@tsparticles/react";
import { IOptions, RecursivePartial, type Container, type ISourceOptions } from "@tsparticles/engine";
import { loadSlim } from "@tsparticles/slim";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

interface Props {
  options: RecursivePartial<IOptions>;
  className?: string;
}

export const ParticleBackground = ({ options, className }: Props) => {
  const [init, setInit] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    initParticlesEngine(async (engine) => {
      await loadSlim(engine);
    }).then(() => {
      setInit(true);
    });
  }, []);

  const particlesLoaded = async (container?: Container): Promise<void> => {};

  if (init) {
    return (
      <>
        <Particles id="tsparticles" particlesLoaded={particlesLoaded} options={options} className={cn(className)} />
      </>
    );
  }

  return <></>;
};

Expected results
Interactivity is disabled below a screen width of 1024px
Actual results
No effect is made to interactivity at all no matter the screen size
Tried

using loadFull instead of loadSlim.
reversing the interactivityDisabled and interactivityEnabled objects positions.
restarting the NextJS app.
searching the internet for any available solutions.

